# Is there a word for situations that you have no control over?

Tags: single-word-requests

As in we can't choose our  race, birthplace etc.

Comment: Welcome atif. What research have you done to answer this question yourself? Please tell us what it is you don't understand about what you have read? If you were unable to find anything, what did you google? You can [edit] your answer to provide more detail. Please take the [tour] and read up in our [help] section about how we work here.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of such words.

It is your **lot**.

It is your **doom**.

It is your **fate**.

It is your **fortune**.

It is your **destiny**.

Comment: Or, being a little less dramatic, you could say it is a **given**.

Comment: @Kate Bunting: Yes, in many contexts the phrase "a given" would also work. But it would have to include the indefinite article, which OP might not know. As you know, we wouldn't say "It is your given" or "It was his given" or "It was the given of the ship to sink".